# NUnit tests being aborted randomly (Involves ServiceStack & RavenDB)

Tags: nunit, servicestack, ravendb

## NUnit tests being aborted randomly (Involves ServiceStack & RavenDB)

We have a project where we use ServiceStack and RavenDB. Testing is done using NUnit.

When running the tests individually everything works fine.
When running more than one test a few will do their thing (pass/fail) but very often one of the tests will be aborted and all subsequent tests will not be run.
Which test aborts is seemingly random. The more tests that are being run the higher the chance that one will be aborted.
The test that gets aborted does seem to be able to run through all its actions though seeing from the test log.

Unfortunately I'm not able to give more info besides the following files which show the way our tests are set up.

- [IntegrationBaseTest.cs](http://ideone.com/l9NS41) (Base test class)
- [GlobalSetupFixture.cs](http://ideone.com/Wpc4xG)
- [AccountServiceTests.cs](http://ideone.com/hlDayj) (Example file with tests)
- [test log](http://ideone.com/NKhukb) (Log of aborted test, in this case DeleteAccount_DeletesAccount)
- Result view of running all tests in `AccountServiceTests.cs`.
  Which test gets aborted is completely random.
  [image: Failing test view]

Does anyone have any idea of what I could try to fix this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that when disabling the logging the tests ran normally without aborting.
I'm not sure what caused them to abort but I think it might be because the jetbrains taskrunner was running out of memory because of all the logs.